# C++: How can I output data as CSV to a specific set of cells in an existing file?

Tags: c++, csv, ofstream

So I am looping over data files in order to make a calculation based on each data file (the calculation is done for 20 bins in each file, so 20 results per file). I then want to get each calculation into a csv file so that I am able to average the calculations from each file.

Each time I loop over a file, I am obtaining a csv file with 20 results in cells A1 to A20.

However, what I want is a csv file with 20 results in cells A1 to A20, another 20 results in cells B1 to B20 etc. up to 20 results in cells CV1 to CV20.

My code in each loop looks like this for outputting the data:

```
ofstream ofs (path2 + "tanShears.csv", ofstream::out);
for (int j = 0; j < r.size(); j++) {
    ofs << tShears[j] << endl;
```

Obviously when I do this I just end up with 20 results in cells A1 to A20 corresponding to the final data set in the loop, since each loop just overwrites the previous one.

Any ideas how I can target specific cells in the csv file, so that I can output the results from each loop to a different part of the same csv file?

Comment: Read in the whole file into a vector of vectors, change the part you need to change, and write the whole thing back.

Comment: Alternatively, don't close and reopen the output file all the time. Open it once at the start of the outer loop, iterate over all of your data files, and only then close it.

Comment: Don't open ofstream each time, open it one time and write to it consecutively

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is structured like this:

```
[A1];[B1];[C1];...\n
[A2];[B2];...\n
[A3];[B3];...\n
```

If you don't want to write the whole data at once, you will have to read the whole file, parse it, make changes accordingly and then writing it. Which I would avoid at almost any cost.

Now to some example code: (I am assuming you are printing some int value)

```
void writeToCSV(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& tShears)
{
    ofstream ofs (path2 + "tanShears.csv", ofstream::out);
    for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator j = tShears.begin(); 
         j != tShears.end(); j++) 
    {
        for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = j->begin(); i < j->end(); j++)
        {
            ofs << i << ";";
        }
        ofs << std::endl;
    }
    ofs.close();
}
```

In this example the inner vector contains the n-th values of all calculations you made. So it might contain A1, B1, C1...

Comment: OK this looks good. So would I then - within my loop over the data files - simply include the function "writeToCSV(tShears);" (tShears is the final 20-element vector that I get on each loop)??

Comment: in my example tShears is a vector containing vectors of integer values. You should only use the vector in your Loop over the data files. After you are done Looping you call the writeToCSV function.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the results in a vector (one block of 20 after another, or use different vectors).

Then write all data at once. The first value of each block on the first line in your csv, then the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/#parameters

You should write sth like this:

```
ofstream ofs (path2 + "tanShears.csv", ofstream::out|ofstream::app);
```

You can store your all results in vector, but if calculation is a long process (it takes a hours), there is possibility of loss this data (when sth go wrong), and in this case better is write your results to file after each part of calculation.

However, writing to file full data seems be faster then many writings partial data.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly your question?
You have 20 data sources with csv data, 20 results in each one. And you need to operate with these data with later writing each data set to the file?

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct privateData {
  map<string,vector<vector<string>>> allData;
  void addDataUnit(const string& block, const vector<string>& unit)
  {
    // I consider that you already parsed csv data into separated elements
    allData[block].push_back(unit);
  }
  string getDataRow(const string& block, int position) {
    string ret;
    if (allData[block].size() >= position) return ret;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < allData[block][position].size(); i++) {
      ret+=allData[block][position][i];
      ret+="SomeDelim";
    }
    return ret;
  }
  vector<string> getDataBlock(const string& block) {
    vector<string> ret;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < allData[block].size(); i++)
      ret.push_back(getDataRow(block,i));
    return ret;
  }

}
```

I didn't compile - so, probably some syntax errors. 
So, each dataBlock will be named array for a cell set.
Then you can iterate the map to get all names and write them to separate files or to separate data set.
Hope it helps